# Node.js orm2 create elements in loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, coffeescript

My code inserts two times the same values from array (last one). Why ? How to insert many rows but only if they doesn't exists ?

```
        for x of species # two elements 36 and 37
            data = { movie_id : id, species_id : species[x].id }
            console.log data
            MovieSpecies.exists data, (err, exists) ->
                if exists == false
                    MovieSpecies.create data, (err, items) ->
                        console.log items
```

Comment: Can you shared the definition of `MovieSpecies` and what you're seeing as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making an async call to MovieSpecies.exists within the loop.  When you want to loop over a list and do async calls I do something like this:

```
urls = ['http://cnn.com', 'http://cnet.com']

do_loop = (index) ->
  if index == urls.length
    alert 'all done!'
  else
    http_get urls[index], (result) ->
      do_loop index+1

do_loop 0
```